# Matlab equivalent to the asterisk in Python when giving inputs to a function

Tags: python, list, function, matlab

What I would like to achieve in Matlab is the following:

I have a function which takes some inputs.

```
f(x,y)
```

Now I have a list of which I would like to pass to the function in which each entry stands for one input of the functions.

```
f(x,y) = f([x,y])
```

I know that this is possible in Python like this:

```
f(x,y) = f(*[x,y])
```

What do I do in Matlab?

Thank you!

Comment: not sure if you can, its definetly not the standard way of doing MATLAB. Just index the input list.

Comment: What is the actual function you are trying to call? The general answer is what Ander has pointed out, but there exist functions for which `f([a b],[x y])` is equivalent to `[f(a,x) f(b,y)]`. Exploiting this vectorization property when available might improve performance.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a cell array. If `x = {a,b}` then `f(x{:})` is equivalent to `f(a,b)`. Under the hood matlab automatically expand `f(x{:})` as `f(x{1},x{2},...)`

For example, if we want to concatenate several strings:

```matlab
x1 = 'A'
x2 = 'B'
x3 = 'C'
s = strcat(x1,x2,x3) % s = 'ABC'
```

is equivalent to

```matlab
x = {'A','B','C'}    % Our cell 
s = strcat(x{:})     % s = 'ABC'
```